# How to subset on Python dictionary values, and delete the others?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Using `Counter()` with Python3.x, I created a script that would count the number of characters in a text file, and then output a python dictionary for each file.

```
import glob
from collections import Counter

files = glob.glob("*.txt")
for f in files:
    for line in f:
        filename, contents = line.strip().split()
        results[filename] = Counter(line)
```

Here is the output:

```
{ "textfile1.txt": Counter({'C': 23426, 'T': 5111, ' ': 4231, 'l': 3321, 'G': 353, '4': 2987797, 'R': 2, 'B': 223185, 'r': 186587}) }
```

The value of the key-value pairs includes key-value pairs within `Counter()` which shows the number of counters per each character, e.g. `"character": # of characters`.

My question: Given these values, how do I only select certain characters, e.g. only `C` and `T` and delete all of the others.

My idea would be some sort of list comprehension:

```
dictionary1 # original dictionary above
correct_keys = ["C", "T"]
corrected_dictionary1 = {k: v for k, v in dictionary1.values().split if values in correct_keys}
```

That doesn't quite work; here's the error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Why do you think you can use `split` here? `.split` is a `str` method... just remove it. Also, `values` i a name that is not defined. I think you mean `v`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's obviously a mistake. I'm trying to "split" up the `dictionary1` values, which are individually key-value pairs.

Comment: ... right, that's what you did when you unpacked that tuple into `k,v`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I mean split the values `v` into key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, You need to run through the first dict which his key is the file name, and than run through the internal dict and in the end check whether it is in the `correct_keys`

```
from collections import Counter
dictionary1 = { "textfile1.txt": Counter({'C': 23426, 'T': 5111, ' ': 4231, 'l': 3321, 'G': 353, '4': 2987797, 'R': 2, 'B': 223185, 'r': 186587}),
                "textfile2.txt": Counter({'C': 23427, 'T': 5112, ' ': 4231, 'l': 3321, 'G': 353, '4': 2987797, 'R': 2, 'B': 223185, 'r': 186587})}
correct_keys = ["C", "T"]

def filter_dict_results(items):
    tmp_dict = [{k : v} for k,v in items if k in correct_keys]
    ret = {}
    for elem in tmp_dict:
        ret.update(elem)
    return [ret]

corrected_dictionary1 = [res_dict for (k, v) in dictionary1.items() for res_dict in filter_dict_results(v.items())]
print corrected_dictionary1
```

**Output:**

```
[{'C': 23426, 'T': 5111}, {'C': 23427, 'T': 5112}]
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks!
However, this works correctly is the dictionary `dictionary1` has only one ke-value pair. If there are multiple keys, then it combines all results together. The correct way might be `for item in list(dictionary1.items())`, and then replace `dictionary1.items()` after the for statement

Comment: @ShanZhengYang , You are right, What you need is complicating a bit but I've updated the code to what you need, Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for the help. The question is answered, but in the interest of learning: Using your list comprehension, how would I create a dictionary which includes the filename? I could create a tuple with a filename and the dictionary `res_dict` with`[ (k, res_dict) for (k, v) in dictionary1.items() for res_dict in filter_dict_results(v.items())]`